# How to create Batch file to execute sql script

Tags: java, mysql, batch-file, inno-setup

I'm in the last step to create an installation of a java swing application with inno setup.
In this installation I call a batch file that get the installation of mysql . My problem is that I want to call a sql script from a batch file, that's what I do  but it's doesn't work:

```
@echo off
C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.1\bin\mysql -u root -p password < dbase.sql;
```

**(  **'dbase.sql***' in this script a create the database with tables).*

and here I execute that batch file in inno setup:

```
[Run]

Filename: "C:\Documents and Settings\esolutions\Mes documents\dumps\install.bat"; Flags: shellexec waituntilterminated
```

So when I install the program. I run mysql command line and I find that the script is not executed (no database created)

Comment: Don't hardcode paths and maybe you'll be fine.

Comment: sorry what do you mean?

Comment: Does that command work run running it directly from the comamnd prompt?

Comment: @Majda he means you should only write `mysql ...` instead of `C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.1\bin\mysql`

Comment: if I write only mysql that doesn't work..it works now

Comment: Yes, you overcame a problem without seeing another one. Good luck with customer support ;-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to omit the space after -p too.

```
@echo off
"C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.1\bin\mysql" -u root -ppassword < dbase.sql;
```

Comment: Its a basic principle of MySQL, that **-p** cannot have any space after that.

Answer (score 0):

Change your script as below

```
@echo off
"C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.1\bin\mysql" -u root -p password < dbase.sql;
```

Comment: Thanks @Amit that execute something but not executing the script. I don't know what can I do

Comment: it gives no error message but when I look on mysql command (on windows) I see that no database is created so the sql script is not executed..but it shows some execution

Comment: Are you sure, the database script is in the same directory? Try to give the script file including the full path i.e. `C:/Documents/dbase.sql`

Comment: yes it's in the same directory now it works I do like @vidulahasaranga  says